# Drupal node creation - back to origin after creation

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

I have organic groups setup and within those group users are allowed to post certain content.
What I woulkd like to do is, when you create a node inside an organic group, it automatically defaults back to frontpage of the group, or the same page that I used to create the node.

At present it defaults to the node view page.I assume there must be a way to add some kind of code so that after the node creation it defauls back to its origin. I.E. the page from where the node was created from.

thanks :)
UPDATE: Got the below, but not entirly sure how to ensure that it redirects back to the GROUP node, from where it was created,

```
<?php 

/**
* Grabs current node ID
*/

$node_nid = nid; 

/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
  function mod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mod_form_finish_redirect';
  unset($form['buttons']['preview']);
}

/**
 * Custom submit handler. Overwrites the form redirection variable.
 */

function mod_form_finish_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/content/<?php print $node_nid; ?>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module. Rules is a great module that allows you to do many kinds of workflow and it is perfect for this.  You can write a rule that triggers when a specified node type is created (and include any other conditions you require as well).  After the node is created you can specify a redirect action rule to the home page.  This can all be done without any code.

Answer (score 0):

Rules (as 'We Love Drupal' says) is a possibility, but also quite a big module for such a small change in behavior. Another option is to write a custom module implementing [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) setting the [#redirect value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect) of the form.

Keep in mind that of seeing the node you have just created is important feedback for a user. When you perform an action, you want confirmation that you have achieved your task. While it's technically possible to do what you ask, it may be bad for usability.

Comment: <?php 

/**
* Grabs current node ID
*/

$node_nid = nid; 

/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
  function mod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mod_form_finish_redirect';
  unset($form['buttons']['preview']);
}
 
/**
 * Custom submit handler. Overwrites the form redirection variable.
 */

function mod_form_finish_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = '/content/<?php print $node_nid; ?>';
}
?>

Comment: That's not valid PHP, but it looks like you're headed in the right direction. Maybe you don't even need a custom submit handler. See also http://drupal.org/node/134000.

Comment: anyway you could help me along, I have no clue about php or other code

Comment: If you have no clue about coding, the solution with Rules module may be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirment. Rules worked for me.